# MySQL datetime on Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a datetime field on my table, and I need to, on my Java code, get only the hour.

I mean, I have the data on my resultSet and need to get the result (the hour) and put on my setHour method.

Basically:

On my DB (the field is DATETIME):

SELECT hourField FROM extra;

1000-01-01 00:00:00

On my model class I have the var and gets and sets:

```
private Date hourField;

public Date getHourField() {
    return hourField;
}

public void setHourField(Date hourField) {
    this.hourField = hourField;
}
```

And on the code I want to take the data from the DB:

```
ModelClass model = new ModelClass();

model.setHourField(result.getDate("hourField"));
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I got it! It was so simple.

As I said, my field in DB is DATETIME, and my var on Java is Date. So, when executing the method above, I got only the date.

So I changed, instead using getDate, I'm now using getTime, and it works.

Comment: first of all show us some code...

Answer (score 0):

First you'll have retrieve the date from the resultset:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp("dateField");

Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp.getTime());
```

You can obtain the hour using the folowing line of code:

```
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

More detailed examples can be found here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples

Comment: Should that be `java.sql.Timestamp` rather than `Date`? And `getTimestamp` rather than `getDate`?

Comment: No, you can retrieve the date as a `java.sql.Date` object. More information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html?is-external=true.

Comment: The Question says: `the field is DATETIME`

Comment: You're right, it should be `java.sql.Timestamp`. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, use the java.time framework.

First convert from `java.sql.Timestamp` to an `Instant`, a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
java.sql.Timestamp tz = myResultSet.getTimestamp( … );
Instant instant = tz.toInstant();
```

Apply the desired/expected time zone to get an hour-of-day that makes sense. Your `Instant` may be 12 noon in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), but that would mean 7 AM in Québec, for example. Or 8 AM under Daylight Saving Time (DST) depending on the value’s date. So you need a time zone adjustment to have meaning in your particular context.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Extract your hour-of-day by calling [`getHour`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#getHour--).

```
int hour = zdt.getHour();
```